# Realm + NSClassFromString

Tags: realm, swift3

Hi everyone and thank you for be reading this.

I am new with Realm and I am stucked with a function that I can't figure out how to build. My intention is to have one function called `func delete(className:String, id:Int){` that should be able to delete any object of any Realm class by its ID. The inner code of the function is:

```
func delete(objectNameV:String, id:Int){

   let theClass = NSClassFromString(objectNameV)

   // Get the default Realm
   let realm = try! Realm()
   let queryResult = realm.objects(theClass as! Object.Type).filter("id = \(id)")
   try! realm.write {
      realm.delete(queryResult)
   }
}
```

But the fact is that `let theClass = NSClassFromString(objectNameV)` it's allways NIL.

Any help is appreciated, **i just need a function that given a realm classname and the id from an object of that class can delete it**!

Realm version: 2.0.1
Xcode version: 8

Comment: I think instead of objectNameV:String parameter, you should pass object:Object parameter instead and update your query to realm.objects(object.self).filter("id = \(id)")

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html), classes in Swift are namespaced by their module names. So it's not sufficient to simply write the class name; you must also include their module name as well.

The example Apple used on their website is:

```
let myPersonClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString("MyGreatApp.Person")
```

Comment: I saw that and tried it out but with no good result at all. Have you or anyone been able to try it ? Anyway tomorrow I will take a further look on and comment back here.